# I couldn't using bootstrap $uibModal is undefined

Tags: angularjs, angular-ui-bootstrap

I am trying to use bootstrap but I couldn't
this is my app.js

I want to use bootstrap with my users module

```
  angular.module('Authentication', []);
    angular.module('Home', []);
    angular.module('menuBar',[])
    angular.module('register',[])
    angular.module('register',[])
    angular.module('UserValidation',[])
    angular.module('users',['ui.bootstrap'])
    angular.module('smart-table',[])
    angular.module('ui.bootstrap',[])

    angular.module('mb', [
        'Authentication',
        'Home',
        'ngRoute',
        'ngCookies',
        'menuBar',
        'register',
        'UserValidation',
        'users',
        'smart-table',
        'ui.bootstrap'
    ])
```

and I added the js file in my index.jsp

```
 <script src="//angular-ui.github.io/bootstrap/ui-bootstrap-tpls-0.14.1.js"></script>
```

and this is my controller

```
      'use strict';
    angular.module('users').controller('usersListController', ['userService', function (service, $uibModal) {

      var ctrl = this;

      this.displayed = [];
      // filter for user type
      this.obj1={userType: '0'};
      this.obj2={userType: '1'};
      this.obj3={userType: '2'};

      this.isShown = function(type) {
          return type === this.filterOption;
      };

      this.filterOption;


      this.openUser = function (row) {

            var modalInstance = $uibModal.open({
                    animation: $scope.animationsEnabled,
                    templateUrl: 'js/users/user-modal.jsp',
                    controller: 'MonitoringModalController',


);  
   };
```

but when I run it I get this error:

> angular.js:12520 TypeError: Cannot read property 'open' of undefined

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You forget **$uibModal** inside inline annotation.

```
['userService', '$uibModal', function (service, $uibModal)
                    ^^^^
```

Answer (score 0):

Remove

```
angular.module('ui.bootstrap',[])
```

This line means "create module `ui.bootstrap`". Empty module. Effectively you overwrite `ui.bootstrap` module.

Answer (score 0):

you should not create ui.bootstrap module, because this is provided by angular ui bootstrap.

```
angular.module('ui.bootstrap',[])
```

Delete above line of code.